# In Objective-c, is a Block an object type?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In Objective-C, is a Block an object? Can it be retained/released? Can it be sub-classed?

Comment: Subclassed? Nope. Retained? Yes.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It make sense to me.

Comment: While it can't really be "subclassed" so to speak, you can do something very similar. Check out this article, which makes a version of dispatch_block_t that can be cancelled: http://sebastienthiebaud.us/blog/ios/gcd/block/2014/04/09/diggint-into-gcd-1-cancel-dispatch-after.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's an object type.

However it's mostly handled by the compiler, so you can't subclass it and you have very little control over memory management. You typically can only `copy` it to the heap, in case it outlives the scope it's declared in.

Concretely, at runtime a block is an instance of either `__NSMallockBlock__`, `__NSStackBlock__` or `__NSGlobalBlock__`. You can read more on the subject here: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/how-blocks-are-implemented-and.html

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this, for example:

```
- (void)doSomeStuffWithABlock 
{
    void(^myBlock)(NSUInteger, NSString *, NSString *) = ^(NSUInteger index, NSString *string, NSString *string) {
        // Do stuff
    };

    myBlock(1, @"two", @"three");  // Set breakpoint here to inspect myBlock.
}
```

In the debugger:

```
(lldb) po myBlock
<__NSMallocBlock__: 0x17d21f20>

(lldb) p * myBlock
(__block_literal_generic) $1 = 0x001cc801 MyApp`__68-[MyObject myMethod]_block_invoke + 1 at MYMyObject.m:218

(lldb) p (BOOL)[myBlock isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]
(BOOL) $5 = YES
```

You can send it `retain` / `release`, if you're not using ARC.  You can also ask for it's `retainCount`.  However block.h declares these macros that you should use:

```
#define Block_copy(...) ((__typeof(__VA_ARGS__))_Block_copy((const void *)(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define Block_release(...) _Block_release((const void *)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

I don't think you can subclass it, since no headers publicly expose `__NSMallocBlock__` or related Block types (see comments) (that I could find), and I suspect down that road lies nothing but the most excruciating pain, since you'll be trying to trick the compiler.  I'm not sure why you'd even want to do that.  If you need to add functionality, consider creating your own object that wraps a `@property` that is the actual block to execute.  Or consider using [NSBlockOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSBlockOperation).

Comment: For my personal interest, on which OS version did you tried that?

Comment: The latest iOS 7.1.whatever.

Comment: Real device or simulator?

Comment: I tested it on a real device.  I don't see that it would make a difference though.

Comment: Blocks are `__NSGlobalBlock__` instances on Yosemite... I was just wondering about the class name change... : )

Comment: I suspect if you declare it inside of a selector (which I did) instead of a global C function, you'll get an `__NSMallocBlock__`.

Comment: Still `__NSGlobalBlock__`... And it's also the case with iOS 8 by the way... Interesting ^^

Comment: `NSGlobalBlock` represents a block with no reference to the surrounding context and it's saved in the global storage. That's the main difference with `NSMallocBlock`.

Comment: then it also depends on the level of optimizations. With no optimizations in place most blocks are just copied to the heap, so you get `NSMallockBlock`s, whereas if you turn optimizations on you get lots of `NSStackBlock`s whenever possible.

Comment: Damn right! When capturing a variable, the class is indeed `__NSMallocBlock__`. Thank you sir : )

Comment: Ah, there you go.  I had omitted that as well, but I was capturing various things.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gabriele's answer, which is correct, you can see it by sending a `class` message to a block:

```
#import <objc/message.h>

int main( void )
{
    void ( ^ block )( void ) = ^( void )
    {};

    NSLog( @"%@", ( ( id ( * )( id, SEL ) )objc_msgSend )( ( id )block, @selector( class ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

A non-object type would eventually crash, but with a block, you'll get `__NSGlobalBlock__` printed, meaning a block is a real (even if obviously special) instance of an Objective-C class.

Comment: that's just a very verbose way of writing `[block class]`